# no authResponse when login via FB.login() for test user

Tags: oauth, authorization, facebook-javascript-sdk

I try to build a facebook app with the javascript SDK. I would like to login to my app and tried that using the following instructions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/#step4

My full code now looks something like this:

```
if(jQuery) (function(jQuery){

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div>');
    FB.init({appId: MY_APP_ID, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true});

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if(response.status === "connected") {
            console.log("welcome facebook user.");
        } else if (response.status === "not_authorized") {
            console.log("not authorized");

            FB.login(function(loginStat) {
                if(loginStat.authResponse) {
                    console.log("now logged in");
                    console.log(loginStat);
                } else {
                    console.log("still not authorized");
                    console.log(loginStat);
                }
            });
        }   
    });
});
```

})(jQuery);

I can use this code to log myself in with the Facebook account I created that app with but if I try to login with my test Facebook account the "register your app" popup will show up and I can click "Go to App". But it will always end up in the "still not authorized" branch with the loginStat object looking like this: status="not_authorized", authResponse=null.

Anyone know why ?